# Apache POI Excel - Search and replace text

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, portability

I'm working with Java development system that involves saving the data to an Excel file instead of saving to Database. This was one of the client's requirement.

I've done creating Excel file using Apache POI from Java so problem with that. But now I want to have more portable way to do that.

I want to have an Excel template, in this way user can design their own output. Data will be inserted to Excel by placeholder replacement.

My problem is that, is there a way to replace some text in Excel using Apache POI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think POI has this inbuilt. Its a low level API to read and write Excel on any environment, even one where excel is not installed nor could be (works on the binary file format only). So you would have to build this yourself but not too difficult.

Have made a project where the user could name cells with certain values and then the code would look for those and use those as hints of where to insert data.So its possible but you need to come up with the format and write code to go thru the first n rows yourself depending on the requirements.

We used to parse the first 10 rows and 50 columns to find out where to put header info, summaries etc, and then the detail data, and move to another sheet of data more than x rows. It worked so well that the code that was written for 1 report was usable for 2 others with no modifications.

For the database side - had to define queries and then refer to them in another property sheet.

The notation was something like this

```
q1=select c1,c2 ... where c1=p1 and c2=p2

q2=select c1,c2,c3 from ... where c1 = p3
```

Where p1, p2 where parameters from config, environment and screen.

Then in the sheets where found chars {- and -} with query id and column id between them example:

```
 {-q1.c1-}
```

would parse that to get the query id and column number, if there was only one result replace it in place (summary data), else replace it there and in rows below.

These could be part of a excel formula too - the formula would be invalud when the excel is made by the user, but after we replaced the values they would start to work.

If current excel has issues with putting invalud formula you could accept the templates in a property table - specifyinf column id and row number, and the  excel formula including the strings to be replaced with your program's values

Comment: I've read your answer and somehow doesn't meet my requirements. We won't working with a database server, so I can't have an SQL query. But I understand what you have done in your done in your project. By the way, I figured out my misery an hour after I posted this question. I'll post it in to answer my question so that anybody can also use it as a base code. And also **thank you** for sharing your ideas.

Comment: Due to my low reputation, I can't still answer my question. I'll post it right here,

`I've managed to have an Excel template that contains placeholders. In this way, users can customized their Excel report depending on developers given placeholders.

Here's the link for the code:
**http://pastebin.com/kKfLTwcY**

Used pastebin to post the whole source for the whole class.

If you'll need the source for OSValidator,
**http://pastebin.com/ybVZR2yJ**

I hope this helps for everyone!`